# Changing a single cell value in a large raster

Tags: r, raster

I've got a rasterbrick, with layers of climate data on islands, surrounded by NA ocean cells. I'd like to set a few of the ocean cells to the value of the coast nearby. Having a surprising amount of trouble doing this. In my mind the code should be something like below, but I run out of memory. The rasters are large approx 2500x2500.

```
# dummy stack with three layers
slogo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
# let's say cell 5 is the one I want to change
newvals <- 1000*(1:3)
for(i in 1:nlayers(slogo)) slogo[[i]][5] <- newvals[i]
```

Subsequent step will be writing the rasters to separate ascii files; so an alternative hacky solution might be snipping into the text file and replacing single values...

EDIT: 
Perhaps there's a solution someone can recommend by resetting memory allocation limits? Here's the error message I show after running on my large raster.

`Error: cannot allocate vector of size 504.1 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readBin(raster@file@con, what = dtype, n = nc, dsize, dsign,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3979Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In readBin(raster@file@con, what = dtype, n = nc, dsize, dsign,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3979Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: closing unused connection 4 (C:\Users\jcw\AppData\Local\Temp\R_raster_jcw\r_tmp_2015-08-16_130255_2000_11926.gri) 
4: In getBilData(object, r = startrow, nrows = nrows, c = startcol,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3979Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In getBilData(object, r = startrow, nrows = nrows, c = startcol,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3979Mb: see help(memory.size)
6: In getBilData(object, r = startrow, nrows = nrows, c = startcol,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3979Mb: see help(memory.size)
7: In getBilData(object, r = startrow, nrows = nrows, c = startcol,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3979Mb: see help(memory.size)`

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, it's just an indexing issue:

```
library(raster)

# dummy stack with three layers
slogo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 

##  Check values of all three bands at cell 5:
slogo[5]
```

Yields:

```
     red green blue
[1,] 255   255  255

##  Set values of all three bands to zero:
slogo[5][1:3] <- 0

slogo[5]
```

Yields:

```
     red green blue
[1,]   0     0    0
```

An alternative that might get the OP past the memory issues of processing all of the bands at once:

```
##  Alternatively, load each band into memory separately, do the
##    replacement and write each band back to disk as a separate GeoTiff:
for (i in 1:nbands(slogo)) {
    r <- raster(slogo, layer=i)
    r[5] <- 0
    writeRaster(r, file=paste0("band_", i, ".tif"), format="GTiff")
}
```

Comment: This works in the example, but does not overcome the memory problem in my large raster: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 504.1 Mb`

Comment: Hmm, I see from your edit that you only have 4GB of RAM.  This is going to severely cramp your style working with rasters, especially on a Windows machine where overall RAM usage tends to leave less for R to work with.  If you're going to write these values to disk eventually anyway, you could try my edit above but you may be stuck doing something a bit more convoluted depending on the overall size of the rasters you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `raster::update` function to change values in raster files on disk (do make backups!)